# Weiß jemand, wo der Begriff "Pardune" herkommt?

Tags: etymology, technical-terminology

Bisweilen stolpert man über Wörter, auch in der eigenen Muttersprache, die man wirklich noch nie gehört hat.

[image]
**Pardune** ist so eins. Damit werden anscheinend die schrägen Fußpunkte für Abspannseile und diese Seile selbst von z.B. Sendemasten oder an Schiffen in der Takelage bezeichnet. Sucht man nach der Herkunft dieses Wortes, findet man vage Verweise auf Niederländisch und Italienisch, aber keine schlüssige Herkunft. Ngrams findet das Wort überhaupt nicht, und der Duden hat nur einen kurzen Verweis und sagt lapidar "Herkunft ungeklärt".

Wer weiß, wo das Wort herkommt?

Comment: "Pardun, das. Die Parduns sind stehendes Gut und stützen die Stengen nach der Seite und nach hinten zu und verleihen ihnen festen Halt. Die Endung un, oen geschrieben, kommt im Niederländischen, woher das Wort  —  es lautet daselbst perdoen  — stammen wird, häufig vor; [...]. Die Stammsilbe par dürfte [352] von bar, par = tragen kommen, denn das Pardun ist ein tragendes, haltendes, festhaltendes Etwas. Es müßte [...] eigentlich Parun heißen; bar, par [hat] die Neigung, sich mit d weiterzubilden, [...]" (Gödel, Etymologisches Wörterbuch der deutschen Seemannssprache)

Comment: Hier noch die URL (war zu lang für einen einzigen Kommentar): http://www.hellenicaworld.com/Germany/Literature/GustavGoedel/de/Seemannssprache.html#Page_351

Comment: Gute Frage, aber hättest du kein Bild mit schönerem Wetter nehmen können? Man kriegt ja richtig schlechte Laune, wenn man das nur sieht...

Comment: @tohuwawohu  gute Antwort, aber: keins meiner holländischen Wörterbücher kennt das Wort...

Comment: @tofro : VanDale (online) mag es nicht ("Het woord is verkeerd gespeld of het staat niet in het gratis woordenboek."), aber dort ist es zu finden: http://www.debinnenvaart.nl/binnenvaarttaal/woord.php?woord=p

Comment: @stefan ah danke. Wenn du das als Antwort schreibst, mach ich einen Haken dran

Comment: @tohuwawohu warum hast du keine richtige Antwort daraus gemacht? Die Quelle ist doch super. Kommentare sind hingegen nicht für die Beantwortung von Fragen gedacht und bleiben auch nicht für die Ewigkeit erhalten.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VanDale (online) mag es nicht ("Het woord is verkeerd gespeld of het staat niet in het gratis woordenboek."), aber dort ist es zu finden:

debinnenvaart.nl/binnenvaarttaal/woord.php?woord=p

> ~pardoen:
>
> 1> oude benaming voor achterwaarts gerichte stagen in het algemeen.
>
> 2> de stagen van een steng. In de zeevaart: de zijstagen van steng en
>   bramsteng.

Noch eine "Fundstelle" - (digitale bibliotheek voor de Nederlandse letteren) H.M.F. Landolt, Militair woordenboek, 1ste druk 1861-1862.

http://www.dbnl.org/tekst/land016mili01_01/land016mili01_01_0017.php

bzw.

http://www.dbnl.org/tekst/land016mili01_01/land016mili01_01_0014.php#a1822

> De stagen steunen de masten naar voren, het want en de pardoens op de
>   zijden en van achteren. Het want verzekert dus de masten tegen het
>   slingeren, de stagen en de pardoens tegen het stampen.